# Regular post and custom post type permalink wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types, permalinks

Hi everyone i develop wordpress theme localy with xampp i changed the permalink to /%category%/%postname%/ and everythings working good however after i create my custom post type the permalink my regular post links give me error 404 page and my custom post type links working good and when i deactived my custom post type my regular post link working normal again, 2 days searching but without resolute .

**Here is my custom post type code**

```
  <?php 

    function name_post(){
        register_post_type('name',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' =>  'Names', 'wp_hours',
                    'singular_name' => 'Name', 'wp_hours',
                    'all_items' => 'All Names', 'wp_hours',
                    'add_new' => 'Add New', 'wp_hours',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Name', 'wp_hours',
                    'edit' => 'Edit', 'wp_hours',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Name', 'wp_hours',
                    'new_item' => 'New Name', 'wp_hours',
                    'view_item' => 'View Names', 'wp_hours',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Names', 'wp_hours',
                    'not_found' => 'Nothing found in Database', 'wp_hours',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash', 'wp_hours',
                    'parent_item_colon' => ''
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => 'name',
                'public_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'capaility' => 'post',
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'name'),
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'),
                'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
            ));
    }

    add_action('init','name_post');

    function names_taxonomies(){
        register_taxonomy(
            'Country',
            'name',
            array(
                'label' => __('Conutry'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'country'),
                'hierarchical' => ture,
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy(
            'Age',
            'name',
            array(
                'label' => __('Age'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'age'),
                'hierarchical' => false,
            )
        );
    }

    add_action('init', 'names_taxonomies');

    function my_rewrite_flush() {
        my_custom_posttypes();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_rewrite_flush' );   

 ?>
```

Comment: Have you gone to the permalinks settings in your admin and just hit "save"? This usually fixes things.

Comment: Well you may try this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/